# ERROR is return datas null: Sending data between activities with Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentservice

i have 3 progress activities for signup. I take the informations at first activity and then trying to send directly third activity to signup with firebase. I tried every way that i research but i can't figure it out.

This is my first activity

```
signUpNextButton.setOnClickListener {

        val name = signUpFullname.text.toString()
        val email = signUpEmail.text.toString()
        val password = signUpPassword.text.toString()
        val repassword = signUpPasswordRepeat.text.toString()

        //Sending datas with this method
        val intent = Intent(this, SignUp_Page3::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("user_email", email)
        intent.putExtra("user_password", password)

        startActivity(Intent(this, SignUp_Page2::class.java))
```

}

this is the second one

```
signUpGetCode.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, SignUp_Page3::class.java)) }
```

and this is the last one:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.signup3)

    val intent = getIntent()
    val email = intent.getStringExtra("user_email")
    val password = intent.getStringExtra("user_password")

    signUpComplete.setOnClickListener {

        //Firebase Authentication to create user
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email,
                password
            )
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, LogIn_Page::class.java))
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Account successfully created, please log in.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    finish()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing to the second page via `Intent`, but never pass from second to third page.

First retrieve the info in your second and third page.

```
private var email: String? = null
private var password: String? = null
   
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (intent != null) {
            email = intent.getStringExtra("user_email")
            password = intent.getStringExtra("user_password")
        } else if (savedInstanceState != null){
            email = savedInstanceState.getString("user_email")
            password = savedInstanceState.getString("user_password")
        }

        //TODO rest of onCreate
    }
```

Try passing the info into the third page `Intent`.

Be careful about storing this data in the `Intent`. If you don't implement `onSaveInstanceState` in your second and third page, then you are going to lose the data on a rotation.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putString("user_email", email)
        outState.putString("user_password", password)
    }
```

Also consider using Static String constants for your keys it will make everything much more manageable.

Comment: I understood you but don't know how to apply now. I tried to implement function that you gave me email and password are gonna red because of those are not defined at onSaveInstanceState.  Can you show me to how i will ?

Comment: Sorry yeah, just fixed. Also updated to Kotlin to match your code.

Comment: still somethings are missed .. :(

Comment: Oh hey on the first page you create an Intent and put the values in, but you don't actually use that Intent. You create another new one in startActivity :)

Comment: when i set the codes "email" and "password" that on the onSaveInstanceState are turning to red, because i must write the State out of onCreate method so those are not defined there. sorry btw, i'm not good so much at backend, so this can be annoying to you:(

Comment: You need to have email and password declared at the class level on the second and third page. Also you don't need to do onSaveInstanceState on the first page since you are just retrieving from page.

Comment: i believe i am so close haha, gonna add all codes now, can you check it please :) ?

Comment: :) Yeah! I think you just need to update.
`startActivity(Intent(this, SignUp_Page3::class.java))`

to 
`val intent = Intent(this, SignUp_Page3::class.java)`
`intent.putExtra("user_email", email)`
`intent.putExtra("user_password", password)
 //Starting another activity
`startActivity(intent)`

```

Comment: I checked the toast email and password are coming or not, yeah it is working but now i can't load them to firebase.

Comment: Catch the error that it's throwing like they show here and see what the error is.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

Comment: you are my hero of tonight, thank you cameron, stay peace :)

Answer (score 0):

First1:

```
signUpNextButton.setOnClickListener {

        val name = signUpFullname.text.toString()
        val email = signUpEmail.text.toString()
        val password = signUpPassword.text.toString()
        //Sending datas with this method
        val intent = Intent(this, SignUp_Page2::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("user_email", email)
        intent.putExtra("user_password", password)

        //Starting another activity
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

second1:

```
 private var email: String? = null
private var password: String? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.signup2)

    val intent = getIntent()

    if (intent != null) {
        email = intent.getStringExtra("user_email")
        password = intent.getStringExtra("user_password")
    } else if (savedInstanceState != null){
        email = savedInstanceState.getString("user_email")
        password = savedInstanceState.getString("user_password")
    }

    signUpGetCode.setOnClickListener {
        val phone = signUpPhoneNumber.text.toString()

            startActivity(Intent(this, SignUp_Page3::class.java))

    }

}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putString("user_email", email)
    outState.putString("user_password", password)

}
```

third1:

```
private var email: String? = null
private var password: String? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.signup3)

    val intent = getIntent()

    if (intent != null) {
        email = intent.getStringExtra("user_email")
        password = intent.getStringExtra("user_password")
    } else if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        email = savedInstanceState.getString("user_email")
        password = savedInstanceState.getString("user_password")
    }

    signUpComplete.setOnClickListener {

        Toast.makeText(this, email + password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putString("user_email", email)
    outState.putString("user_password", password)

}
```

Toast message give me the null null output.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email.toString(),
                password.toString()
            )
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, LogIn_Page::class.java))
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Account successfully created, please log in.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }

            }
```

this returns "something went wrong" to me